# Phonegap 2.2 Windows 8 :app package for Win Store using Win Certificate Kit - failed with error

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-store-apps, indexeddb

I have built Javascript Blank app(Default with out WinJS) for Windows store using Visual Studio 2012  for Windows 8.

The technologies used in this application are:

- jQuery 1.8.3.

  jQuery Mobile 1.1.0

  HTML5/CSS3

  Javascript

  IndexedDB

  Phonegap

The application is running fine in the Win 8 Simulator.
But, when I create the app package to upload to store and do verification through Windows Certificate Kit, it shows an error which are:

- Bytecode generation of Javascript Syntax error. (Though it is working fine in the Chrome Browser without any Javascript Error)

  Encoding to UTF-8 is not done.

As per the Microsoft Documentation we can create Application using jQuery/jQuery Mobile and submit it to App Store, but the Certification test points an error for those files only.

We also tried the other way for this, that is using Phonegap 2.2.0 for Windows 8 but the same errors were coming while creating App Packages. as per http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%208

If there is any steps to be followed before generating App Packages to submit to App Store than please provide us the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the files who give you an error as UTF-8 encoded files. I think you can do this when you do save as.